# How to infer type from "neighboring" type arguments?

Tags: typescript

Here's a simplified example of what I do:

```
type Store<T extends U, U> = {
  getItem(): U
  setItem(item: T): void
}

const store: Store<string, string> = {
  getItem: function (): string {
    return "item"
  },
  setItem: function (item: string): void {
    return
  }
}

function useStore<S extends Store<T, U>, T extends U, U>(store: S): U {
  return store.getItem();
}

const x = useStore(store) // x is unknown

// I have to write this:
const y = useStore<Store<string, string>, string, string>(store) // y is string
```

The problem is that `x` type is `unknown`, because I'm not specifying type arguments for `useStore`.

I think it's possible to infer x type as `string`, since `useStore` have this relation between `T` and `U`, but probably I'm missing the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need generic parameters to "represent" the store's T and U, as TypeScript should be able to infer those types already from the argument given. All you need to do is extract them out of S:

```
type GetStoreT<S extends Store<unknown, unknown>> = ReturnType<S["getItem"]>
type GetStoreU<S extends Store<unknown, unknown>> = Parameters<S["setItem"]>[0];

function useStore<S extends Store<unknown, unknown>>(store: S): GetStoreU<S> {
  return store.getItem();
}
```

The way you extract them can vary, and if you think it's too much work to maintain these types, you could instead use `infer`:

```
type GetStoreT<S extends Store<unknown, unknown>> = S extends Store<infer T, any> ? T : never;
type GetStoreU<S extends Store<unknown, unknown>> = S extends Store<any, infer U> ? U : never;

function useStore<S extends Store<unknown, unknown>>(store: S): GetStoreU<S>;
function useStore(store: Store<unknown, unknown>) {
  return store.getItem();
}
```

However, because of the conditional type, you'll get errors when you try to return. One workaround would be to move the types into an *overload*, but an important caveat is that you no longer have the return type checked to match the signature by TypeScript.

Alternatively, you could use an assertion, too...

```
return store.getItem() as GetStoreU<S>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysD2AnCAeAKlCAPYEB2AJgM5QCqANGQHxQC8UA3gFBRQDmEwAkrgLYAUASgBcZFlCKceEAQEs+otCKgA3eLIJMAvkyYBjeHiLAJCZKLhJUxxLLxtKNu2xr1mrDtwVQAZgFc8PWBZQyghUSd7RnFWZGA-RDwoACJ5GWTxLXJxSS8ZUX9A4ND+NN4I4Ft7ZTUNaNZYzgS8TO1dUEgoAHFOS2Q0FBhMHHxiWDNUAIBrPHgAdzxKadmFqlcoACUmxLRwVBgAbWTPaV5kgF0qJg7oHuA+iFJB4dxCEgeUZfnFqC-V9YACgBDRBA3icCCIIiDI65U4XKgHAAM5wA3LpCkEQkk-JIPkNsK8xh8-j9SWt+MYrBZlHcHk8YDR3FA4s1TFYAHQnPhCdE6fSGYxQLB0X54iaUiaCVgAehlwqgshIkTYugMRhMIFFuIg+ImKBVjkqzgpVOQ0rlUC1StMVTYQA)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but this change make the inferring work:

```
function useStore<T extends U, U>(store: Store<T, U>): U {
  return store.getItem();
}
```

Comment: Well, I assumed you wanted to use the type of the store as a generic parameter when all's said and done, but if you only wanted the T and U then I guess this works, too. It works for similar reasons I included in my post; this is just the "reverse" version.